# How to retrive likes and dislikes on a video via the YouTube API

Tags: php, youtube, google-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

How to get the dislikes and likes for each video ? I can't find it in the documentation

```
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
    'type' => 'video',
    'channelId' => 'UCCQeAYn0EfUNp2-RpJKbG5Q'
));


foreach($searchResponse['items'] as $result) {
$videoID = $result['modelData']['id']['videoId'];
$thumb = $result['modelData']['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['url'];
$title = $result['modelData']['snippet']['title'];
$description = $result['modelData']['snippet']['description'];
// likes
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) only returns a list of the videos you are searching on.  To get additional information about the video in question you need to go though.
 [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) by adding `part=statistics` you are requesting the stats for the video.

Request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=dQw4w9WgXcQ&key=yourkey
```

Response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/8SpkSG4HF2m1G_UwLNJSMOMb1ws\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/OZ6HKyY4VjtP3NjwRxAIOM14bts\"",
   "id": "dQw4w9WgXcQ",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "293285349",
    "likeCount": "1803097",
    "dislikeCount": "87376",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "413069"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Sorry I am not a PHP dev so cant really help much with he code.